# How should I link my Primary Keys and Foreign keys if I have rows containing the same values?

Tags: oracle, constraints, ddl

I have to create a DDL Script using the data provided:
[image]

You can make the following assumptions:

1. Each project has one manager
2. Many employee are assigned to each project. The attribute Hours tells the number of hours each employee has worked on the corresponding project and the attribute rating is the rating that this employee received for his work on this project.
3. Budget and start date refer to the budget and start date of the project
4. Emp_Manager is the manager of the employee and may be different from the project manager

I have already transformed these into 3NF:

```
a.  Employee_T(Emp_Id, Emp_Salary, Emp_dept)
b.  Project_T(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
c.  EmployeeLine_T(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
d.  EmpMgr_T(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
```

This is the DDL I created:

```
BEGIN

  --Bye Tables!
  FOR i IN (SELECT ut.table_name
              FROM USER_TABLES ut) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table '|| i.table_name ||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ';
  END LOOP;

END;

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_T
(
    Proj_Name       VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL,
    Proj_Mgr        VARCHAR2(25),
    Proj_Budget     NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    Start_Date      DATE            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Proj_Name_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (Proj_Name)
);

INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Jupiter','Smith',100000,'15-JAN-2015');
INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Jupiter','Smith',100000,'15-JAN-2015');
INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Jupiter','Smith',100000,'15-JAN-2015');
INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Maxima','Lee',200000,'1-MAR-2014');
INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Maxima','Lee',200000,'1-MAR-2014');
INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Maxima','Lee',200000,'1-MAR-2014');

CREATE TABLE MANAGERS_T
(
    Emp_Dept            NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    Emp_Manager         VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Dept_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Dept)
);

INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (10,'Levine');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (12,'Jones');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (10,'Levine');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (10,'Levine');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (10,'Levine');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (15,'Jones');

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_T
(
    Emp_Id          VARCHAR2(4)     NOT NULL,
    Emp_Salary      NUMBER,
    Emp_Dept        NUMBER          NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Id_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Id),
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Dept_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (Emp_Dept) REFERENCES MANAGERS_T(Emp_Dept)
); 

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E101',60000,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E105',55000,12);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E110',43000,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E101',60000,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E110',43000,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E120',45000,10);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEELINE_T
(
    Emp_Id          VARCHAR(4)     NOT NULL,
    Proj_Name       VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL,
    Hours           NUMBER,
    Rating          NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT EmpID_ProjName_PK
        PRIMARY KEY(Emp_Id,Proj_Name),
    CONSTRAINT Proj_Name_FK    
        FOREIGN KEY (Proj_Name) REFERENCES PROJECT_T(Proj_Name),
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Id_FK    
        FOREIGN KEY (Emp_Id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(Emp_Id)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E101','Jupiter',25,9);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E105','Jupiter',40,0);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E110','Jupiter',10,8);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E101','Maxima',15,0);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E110','Maxima',30,0);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E120','Maxima',15,0);
```

[Here's a GitHub Link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/76342ck/a43bbff5ba4203cda565f8d6ba7ec480/raw/24f66bf0346cb9c9dce2643344808e0459bfb94d/DDL%2520Script)

This is how my tables are supposed to be with their primary keys and foreign keys. When I create the tables, they run fine. The problem is when I start inserting values into them.

I get errors like unique constraint violated because there are values that are repeated. How would I go about this?

Comment: If you wanna insert Proj_Name in more rows in your DDL table you should create primary with atleast a couple of fields

Comment: I don't get what you mean? @Frank

Comment: research NORMALIZATION :: the exercise requires you to remove repetition not to just replicate the data in the image into many tables. e.g. "Jupiter" should occur once in the project table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL is fine, problem is with the insert scripts. Check the below script:

```
BEGIN

  --Bye Tables!
  FOR i IN (SELECT ut.table_name
              FROM USER_TABLES ut) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table '|| i.table_name ||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ';
  END LOOP;

END;

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_T
(
    Proj_Name       VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL,
    Proj_Mgr        VARCHAR2(25),
    Proj_Budget     NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    Start_Date      DATE            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Proj_Name_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (Proj_Name)
);

INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Jupiter','Smith',100000,'15-JAN-2015');
INSERT INTO PROJECT_T
(Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
VALUES ('Maxima','Lee',200000,'1-MAR-2014');

CREATE TABLE MANAGERS_T
(
    Emp_Dept            NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    Emp_Manager         VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Dept_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Dept)
);

INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (10,'Levine');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (12,'Jones');
INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T
(Emp_Dept, Emp_Manager)
VALUES (15,'Jones');

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_T
(
    Emp_Id          VARCHAR2(4)     NOT NULL,
    Emp_Salary      NUMBER,
    Emp_Dept        NUMBER          NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Id_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (Emp_Id),
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Dept_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (Emp_Dept) REFERENCES MANAGERS_T(Emp_Dept)
); 

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E101',60000,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E105',55000,12);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E110',43000,10);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T
(Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept)
VALUES ('E120',45000,10);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEELINE_T
(
    Emp_Id          VARCHAR(4)     NOT NULL,
    Proj_Name       VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL,
    Hours           NUMBER,
    Rating          NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT EmpID_ProjName_PK
        PRIMARY KEY(Emp_Id,Proj_Name),
    CONSTRAINT Proj_Name_FK    
        FOREIGN KEY (Proj_Name) REFERENCES PROJECT_T(Proj_Name),
    CONSTRAINT Emp_Id_FK    
        FOREIGN KEY (Emp_Id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(Emp_Id)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E101','Jupiter',25,9);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E105','Jupiter',40,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E110','Jupiter',10,8);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E101','Maxima',15,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E110','Maxima',30,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T
(Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
VALUES ('E120','Maxima',15,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get errors like unique constraint violated because there are values that are repeated. How would I go about this?

Do not repeat values.

Beyond that, managers are employees:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/907ff/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_T
(
    Emp_Id          VARCHAR2(4)     CONSTRAINT Employee__Emp_Id_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Emp_Salary      NUMBER,
    Emp_Dept        NUMBER          CONSTRAINT Employee__Emp_Dept__NN NOT NULL,
    Name            VARCHAR2(20)
); 

CREATE TABLE MANAGERS_T
(
    Emp_Dept    NUMBER      CONSTRAINT Managers__Emp_Dept__PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Manager_ID  VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT Manager__Manager_ID__FK REFERENCES Employee_T ( Emp_ID )
);

ALTER TABLE Employee_T ADD CONSTRAINT Emp_Dept_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (Emp_Dept) REFERENCES MANAGERS_T(Emp_Dept);

INSERT INTO MANAGERS_T (Emp_Dept, Manager_ID)
SELECT 10,NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12,NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15,NULL FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_T (Emp_Id,Emp_Salary,Emp_Dept,Name)
SELECT 'E101',60000,10,'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E105',55000,12,'Bob' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E110',43000,10,'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E120',45000,10,'David' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E001',NULL,10,'Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E002',NULL,12,'Jones' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E003',NULL,10,'Levine' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E004',NULL,12,'Lee' FROM DUAL;

UPDATE MANAGERS_T SET Manager_ID = 'E003' WHERE Emp_Dept = 10;
UPDATE MANAGERS_T SET Manager_ID = 'E002' WHERE Emp_Dept = 12;
UPDATE MANAGERS_T SET Manager_ID = 'E001' WHERE Emp_Dept = 15;

ALTER TABLE Managers_T MODIFY Manager_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT Managers__Manager_ID__NN NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_T
(
    Proj_Name       VARCHAR2(25)    CONSTRAINT Proj_Name_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Proj_Mgr        VARCHAR2(4)     CONSTRAINT Project__Proj_Mgr__FK REFERENCES Employee_T ( Emp_ID ),
    Proj_Budget     NUMBER          CONSTRAINT Project__Budget__NN NOT NULL,
    Start_Date      DATE            CONSTRAINT Project__Start_Date__NN NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PROJECT_T (Proj_Name, Proj_Mgr, Proj_Budget, Start_Date)
SELECT 'Jupiter','E001',100000, DATE '2015-01-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Maxima','E004',200000,DATE '2014-03-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEELINE_T
(
    Emp_Id          VARCHAR(4)   CONSTRAINT Emp_Id_FK REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_T(Emp_Id),
    Proj_Name       VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT Proj_Name_FK REFERENCES PROJECT_T(Proj_Name),
    Hours           NUMBER,
    Rating          NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT EmpID_ProjName_PK PRIMARY KEY(Emp_Id,Proj_Name)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELINE_T (Emp_Id, Proj_Name, Hours, Rating)
SELECT 'E101','Jupiter',25,9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E105','Jupiter',40,0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E110','Jupiter',10,8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E101','Maxima',15,0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E110','Maxima',30,0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E120','Maxima',15,0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT p.proj_name,
       p.proj_mgr,
       el.emp_id,
       el.hours,
       p.proj_budget,
       p.start_date,
       e.emp_salary,
       m.manager_id,
       e.emp_dept,
       el.rating
FROM   project_t p
       INNER JOIN Employeeline_t el
       ON ( p.proj_name = el.proj_name )
       INNER JOIN employee_t e
       ON ( el.emp_id = e.emp_id )
       INNER JOIN managers_t m
       ON ( e.emp_dept = m.emp_dept )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/907ff/10/0)**:

```
| PROJ_NAME | PROJ_MGR | EMP_ID | HOURS | PROJ_BUDGET |           START_DATE | EMP_SALARY | MANAGER_ID | EMP_DEPT | RATING |
|-----------|----------|--------|-------|-------------|----------------------|------------|------------|----------|--------|
|    Maxima |     E004 |   E120 |    15 |      200000 | 2014-03-01T00:00:00Z |      45000 |       E003 |       10 |      0 |
|   Jupiter |     E001 |   E110 |    10 |      100000 | 2015-01-15T00:00:00Z |      43000 |       E003 |       10 |      8 |
|    Maxima |     E004 |   E110 |    30 |      200000 | 2014-03-01T00:00:00Z |      43000 |       E003 |       10 |      0 |
|   Jupiter |     E001 |   E101 |    25 |      100000 | 2015-01-15T00:00:00Z |      60000 |       E003 |       10 |      9 |
|    Maxima |     E004 |   E101 |    15 |      200000 | 2014-03-01T00:00:00Z |      60000 |       E003 |       10 |      0 |
|   Jupiter |     E001 |   E105 |    40 |      100000 | 2015-01-15T00:00:00Z |      55000 |       E002 |       12 |      0 |
```

Comment: Managers are not employees. If they were then E120 and E150 would have the same managers, right?

Comment: @pyuntae All organisations I know of the managers of the company/departments are also employed by the company and so are employees - your database should reflect real life. E120 and E105 (or E150) do not have to have the same manager if you have built the table correctly.